# StanfordCoreNLP parse Annotation to xmi

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, opennlp

Hi I have such interesting task. Using Java version of [StanfordCoreNLP Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) I parsed text to .xml which you can review [here](https://gist.github.com/svetlanama/fd1ceb006bf94f73b988afc2df310bc4).

And now I need to convert that XML to XMI with all annotation dependencies.
As I understand I need to parse each sentence using `SentencesAnnotation` class 
`List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);`
or [ParserAnnotator](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ParserAnnotator.html). 
So eventually I need to get `SemanticGraph` to be able to go through the edges and save to XMI with appropriate props.

But I am still very mixed if I am on a right way?
Maybe there are some libs, classes or examples which already allow this conversion?

Please share, appreciate any help or advice.
Thanks!